# multiple redirects empties sweet alert session data

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

As i am redirecting during middleware the sweet alert message gets lost, however i would have thought i could just simply put it back into the session.

```
        session(['sweet_alert' => \Session::get('sweet_alert')]);
```

However this does not work, it gets emptied upon the second redirect even if i manually try to add it.

```
public function index()
{

    alert()->success("index - # is now complete", "Success")->persistent("Ok!");

    return redirect('player/create');        
}



public function create()
{
        session(['sweet_alert' => \Session::get('sweet_alert')]);

    if(!empty(\Session::get('sweet_alert'))) {
        // \Session::put('sweet_alert', \Session::get('sweet_alert'));          
        dump('session not empty');
        dump(\Session::get('sweet_alert'));

        return redirect('player/create');
    }

    dd(\Session::get('sweet_alert'));
```

Comment: Could you post your routes code for these 2 functions too?

Comment: Route::resource('player', 'PlayerController');